# How to set bash to run *.exe with mono?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, mono

Without any DE or even X, I want to use `./my.exe` to run `mono my.exe`, like it works with python scripts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash has no such feature. Zsh does, you can set up aliases based on extensions:

```
alias -s exe=mono
```

This would only work in an interactive shell, however, not when a program invokes another.

Under Linux, you can set up execution of foreign binaries through the [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) mechanism; see [Rolf Bjarne Kvinge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47320/how-to-set-bash-to-run-exe-with-mono/47323#47323). Good Linux distributions set this up automatically as part of the mono runtime package.

If you can't use binfmt_misc because you don't have root permissions, you'll have to settle for wrapper scripts.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /path/to/mono "$0.exe" "$@"
```

Put the wrapper script in the same directory as the `.exe` file, with the same name without `.exe`.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible:

- Become root and turn on the binfmt module in your kernel with this command (you may want to add this command to your /etc/rc.local boot script, so that it will be executed on boot):

  `modprobe binfmt`
- Add the line below to your /etc/fstab file:

  `binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc none`
- Then, have your system run the following command on boot:

  `echo ':CLR:M::MZ::/usr/bin/mono:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register`
- Be sure to mark your .exe files as executable in the filesystem as well:

  `chmod +x myprogram.exe`

(from here: [http://mono-project.com/Guide](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#Registering_.exe_as_non-native_binaries_.28Linux_only.29))

Note that this is not the recommended way, read the above mentioned Guide page and also the [page on how to do application deployment](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Deployment) for mono applications.

Comment: I see, truly I better make loader for each .exe I need

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to embed the file inside a bash script using the following guide http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-binary-payload-your-shell-scripts